# Is it possible to use Group seperator (GS) characters in T-SQL like operator?

Tags: sql, t-sql, where-clause, sql-like

I have table containing GS1 barcode information. Each segment of the barcode is separated by FNC1 character, which is a group separator character: CHAR(19). When i want to do wildcard search on the barcode column by including GS charcter in the query, i dont get any results.

```
select * from BARCODE_DATA WHERE BARCODE LIKE '%%'
```

Is this limitation on SQL server?

Thanks,
Jagadish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select * from barcode_date where barcode like '%' + char(19) + '%'
```

Comment: Thanks!,  GMB. That is it.